# Gauss-Lucas theorem proof

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

The Gauss-Lucas Theorem states that:

> All the critical points of a non-constant polynomial $f$ (i.e. the
> roots of $f^{\prime}$ ) lie in the convex hull of the set of zeroes of
> $f$.

Here is a proof of the theorem I found (reference: Mrigank Arora, I couldn't find the full citation.).
I need assistance understanding the rest of the proof from the point where I have an ALL CAPS COMMENT until the end.

Let $f(z)$ be an arbitrary non-constant polynomial with zeroes $z_1,\ldots, z_p$ in the following form
$$
f(z)=(z-z_1)^{m_1}(z-z_2)^{m_2}\ldots (z-z_p)^{m_p},\;n=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}m_j,\;\forall j,\;m_j>0.
$$
Let $F(z)$ be defined as follows for all $z$ such that $f(z)\neq 0$:
$$
F(z)=\frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{d\ell n f(z)}{dz}=\frac{d}{dz}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}m_j\ell n(z-z_j)\right)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}\frac{m_j}{z-z_j}.
$$
Let the conjugate imaginary of $F$ be $\overline{F}(z)$ . Then,
$$
\overline{F}(z)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}\frac{m_j}{\overline{z}-\overline{z_j}}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}m_j\omega_j,\;\omega_j:=\frac{1}{\overline{z}-\overline{z_j}}.
$$
Let $H$ be the convex hull of the set of zeroes of $f$. Assume that $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ is such that $f^{\prime}(z_0)=0$ but $z_0\notin H$. Since $z_0\notin H$, then $f(z_0)\neq 0$, and so $F(z_0)$ is defined. We can see that
$$
\gamma \leq arg(z_j-z_0)<\gamma+\pi,\;j=1,\ldots,p,
$$
where $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$.

I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHAT THE AUTHOR IS DOING FROM THIS POINT TO THE END OF THE PROOF.
This is shown by considering the fact that if there was $arg(z_j-z_0)$ that falls outside this range, then $z_0$ would be inside $H$ because $H$ is convex. Remembering that $\omega_j:=\frac{1}{\overline{z}-\overline{z_j}}$ leads to
$$
arg(-\omega_j)=arg\left(\frac{1}{\overline{z_0}-\overline{z_j}}\right)=-arg(\overline{z_0}-\overline{z_j})=arg(z_0-z_j),
$$
when evaluated at $z_0$. Therefore at $z_0$ we get that $\gamma\leq arg(-\omega_j)<\gamma+\pi$ for all $j$, and so $\gamma\leq arg(-m_j\omega_j)<\gamma+\pi$ for all $j$. Thus (from a lemma in the paper), we get that
$$
\frac{f^{\prime}(z_0)}{f(z_0)}=-1\cdot-\overline{F}(z_0)=-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}-m_j\omega_j\neq 0.
$$
Therefore $f^{\prime}(z_0)\neq 0$, which contradicts the definition of $z_0$.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a simpler explicit argument, actually (I think it’s the same idea, but I find it clearer): let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ be a root of $f’$ but not of $f$.

Then $F(z)=0$, so $\sum_j{\frac{m_j}{\overline{z}-\overline{z_j}}}=0$, thus $z\sum_j{\frac{m_j}{|z-z_j|^2}}=\sum_j{\frac{m_j}{|z-z_j|^2}z_j}$ (1).

Let, for each $j$, $a_j=\frac{m_j}{|z-z_j|^2} > 0$, let $\alpha$ be the sum of the $a_j$ and $b_j=\frac{a_j}{\alpha}$. Then the $b_j$ are positive real numbers adding up to one, and (1) can be rewritten as $z=\sum_j{b_jz_j}$, thus $z \in H$.

Comment: Can you please articulate *why* the line $$z\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}\frac{m_j}{|z-z_j|^2}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}\frac{m_jz_j}{|z-z_j|^2}$$ implies that $z\in H$.

Comment: @user775349: I edited the post, is it clearer to you now?

Comment: Not really. You still haven't explained the *WHY*. Maybe it is obvious to you. H is a convex set (convex hull of the set of zeroes of f), and the $z_j\in H$, $j=1,\ldots,p$. What you have demonstrated, I think, is that $z$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the $z_j$. Is a linear combination of elements of $H$ guaranteed to be in $H$? If so, why? This is my question, in essence.

Comment: It’s not *any* linear combination. It’s a *linear combination* with ***positive** coefficients* that *sum to **one*** – also called a “convex combination”. You can easily show (eg by induction) that convex combinations of points of a convex remain in said convex.

Comment: By your definition, $a_j$ depends on $z$. Thus, $b_j$ depends on $z$ as well.Does this not present some obstacles in the construction of your proof? Why, and why not?

Comment: It doesn’t. I just show that $z$ is a convex combination of the roots of $f$ – the exact coefficients do not matter (and for any point $p \in H$, $p$ will be a convex combination of the roots of $f$, with coefficients depending on $p$).

Comment: If $z$ is *very close* to $z_j$, then $|z-z_j|$ becomes infinitesimally small. Are you not worried about *small divisors* in the summation $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}b_j$? In this case, how do you guarantee that this is a unit sum?

Comment: The $b_j$ are the normalization of the $a_j$, so that their sum is $1$.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ guaranteed to be finite, given that, for some $j$, $|z-z_j|$ may be infinitesimally small?

Comment: If $z$ isn't any of the $z_j$, yes. "Infinitesimally small" is meaningless in this context, because the set of roots of $f'$ not roots of $f$ is at positive distance from the set of roots of $f$.

Comment: Is it possible that $z$ may be *close to* (but not equal to) some $z_j$? If so, what happens to the magnitude of $|z-z_j|$?

Comment: $z$ could indeed be close to some $z_j$, and thus $a_j$ would be large. But $\alpha$ (as the sum of the $a_k$) would be even larger and thus $b_j$ would still be smaller than one.